# django nginx uwsgi deploying fail

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, deploying

I am trying to deploy a simple Django project, but fail all the time. I am [following the instruction here](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#nginx-and-uwsgi-and-test-py).

When I use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` I can see that my site is running:

[image]

In the virtualenv I've installed uWSGI:

```
pip install uwsgi
```

and wrote the `test.py`:

```
# test.py
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"] # python3
    #return ["Hello World"] # python2
```

When running `uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py` I can see

[image]

I then installed en started Nginx:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

I can see

[image]

and then wrote `mysite_nginx.conf`:

```
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 10.211.55.21; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    #location /media  {
    #     alias /path/to/your/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    #}

    #location /static {
     #   alias /path/to/your/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    #}

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/parallels/books/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

because it is just a simple site I commented out the media and static paths, and `uwsgi_params`:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

the directory:

[image]

and run:

```
sudo ln -s ~/home/parallels/books/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

I can see `mysite_nginx.conf` within `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`:

[image]

and then run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

I see nothing in my webbrowser:

[image]

I do not know why, whenever I try deploying a Django site the socket part fails.

Comment: What does your NginX log file say?

Comment: only has access log no error log,,

Comment: how about the uwsgi_params,,,does it something wrong inside?? I just copy past from https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params

Comment: may be I forget to adjust code within  mysite/mysite/wsgi.py ??? I do not do any thing in wsgi.py

Comment: I still do not know ,,how can I deploying,,,.guess django the hardest part is deploying,,,and thaks for your reply ^ ^

Comment: finally I use xml to configure uwsgi and deploying django project successfully,,,.

Comment: You can post your own solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: yes,,I will,thank you ^ ^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django nginx uwsgi ubuntu server deploying fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674353/django-nginx-uwsgi-ubuntu-server-deploying-fail)

Comment: Instead of creating new question, edit your original one to provide all necessary informations.

Comment: thanks for your reply,,it's headache for a newbie to deploying django

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it by using XML to configure uWSGI and deploying Django project successfully. However, this time I do not use a virtualenv.

I created the virtual host configuration `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite`:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name 10.211.55.21;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite-access.log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite-error.log ;

    location / {
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8630;
            include uwsgi_params;
    }

}
```

Then created the `/home/parallels/books/mysite/django.xml` file, note that the name of the file can be anything but should end with `*.xml`:

```
<uwsgi>
    <socket>127.0.0.1:8630</socket>
    <chdir>/home/parallels/books/mysite/mysite</chdir>
    <pythonpath>..</pythonpath>
    <module>wsgi</module>
</uwsgi>
```

the `<chdir>/home/parallels/books/mysite/mysite</chdir>` just point to `<module>wsgi</module>` because there is a `wsgi.py` in `/home/parallels/books/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py`.

I then run the following commands:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
$ uwsgi -x django.xml
```

now the website is reachable:

[image]

But I fail to configure and deploying Django using `uwsgi.ini`.