# Domain Names server set up fail

Tags: nginx, dns

I bought a Domain Names from gandi: "abc.efg"(just an example Domain Name ),and I have an ip address `12.12.12.123`(just an example ip address ),and I can see my website running on `http://12.12.12.123/` , So I want my Domain Names can show my website on, then I set my zone file like this:

[image]

However,when I click the abc.efg it will just shows my nginx server running site, So any one who has any experience about gandi's dns set up?

Answer (score 0):

ok,,I solve my problem,,according my [django deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743124/5678590) ,,,I forgot change my "server_name 10.211.55.21;" to " server_name abc.efg; ",,,now I can see my website on abc.efg